# Why does this C++ link not work? (OSX Mavericks)

Tags: c++, macos

I am learning C++. I have tried linking separate files in an attempt to have a class in a seperate file.

When I build and run the program I get this error message:

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Sally::printCrap()", referenced from:
      _main in Main-8bfa94.o
  "Sally::Sally()", referenced from:
      _main in Main-8bfa94.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
[Finished in 0.3s with exit code 1]

Here is my code:

Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "Sally.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Sally sallyObject;
    Sally *sallyPointer = &sallyObject;

    sallyObject.printCrap();
    sallyPointer->printCrap();
}
```

Sally.h

```
#ifndef SALLY_H
#define SALLY_H

class Sally
{
public:
    Sally();
    void printCrap();
};

#endif
```

Sally.cpp

```
#include "Sally.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

Sally::Sally()
{

}

void Sally::printCrap(){
    cout << "Crap \n";
};
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How do you compile the program? Can you post the command you use? My guess is that you don't compile `Sally.cpp` (and therefore you don't link it). Try `g++ main.cpp a.cpp`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just launch the Terminal application of OS X, then type

cd "/Users/BEASTMACHIENEjr/Desktop/C++ Files" to go to that folder, then type g++ Main.cpp      Sally.cpp. This will produce a file called a.out, which you can then launch by typing ./a.out

PS: if you use `Sublime Text`, I recommend creating a `Makefile` so you can compile code spanned across multiple source files.

Comment: Tells you how little I know about C++.  I figured the compiler would look at the #includes and suck in the necessary files.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, no, it's not like `Java`. In `C++` `#include` is a pre-processor directive that blindly pastes the text from the included file, nothing more. With the addition of modules (sometime in the hopefully not-far-away future), things should become more 21-st century-flavoured.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Includes doesn't tell you where the implementation is. So including `Sally.h` the compiler doesn't know that the implementation file is called `Sally.cpp`. Its just a convention that the header has the same prefix. For instance the file extension could be one of a handful. Examples: `cc` and `cpp` could refer to some c++ file and `c` could refer to some c file that is in the project. Some headers don't even have corresponding implementation file. Also headers don't even need to be in the same directory as the corresponding implementation file. You have to tell the compiler.

Comment: Where do I put "g++ main.cpp sally.cpp"? I do use Sublime Text (2 to be specific), how do I create a "Makefile"?

Comment: Easiest way is to compile from the command line (a terminal). About `Makefile`, there is plenty of documentation on the web, however for your simple project you don't need one, just type the command at a prompt (make sure you are in the same folder with the .cpp files).

Comment: When I put the command in terminal: clang: error: no such file or directory: 'main.cpp'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'sally.cpp'
clang: error: no input files

Comment: Well you have to figure out their location on the disk, then go to that folder. You need probably to learn a bit of UNIX commands, at least the basics, like changing a directory and listing files. Search online, there are plenty of resources.

Comment: They are all at "/Users/BEASTMACHIENEjr/Desktop/C++ Files", what do you mean by "go to that folder". (Sorry if I am being stupid, I am very new to OSX)

Comment: There IS a .exe for Main.cpp, however not for Sally.cpp and Sally.h.

Comment: just lunch the Terminal application of OS X, then type `cd "/Users/BEASTMACHIENEjr/Desktop/C++ Files"` to go to that folder, then type `g++ Main.cpp Sally.cpp`. This will produce a file called `a.out`, which you can then launch by typing `./a.out`

Comment: When I do that, and launch ./a.out. It prints what I need it to do. However when I go to sublime text and build and run it, the same error occurs as before. I also notice that I no longer have main.exe. and a new file called "Sally.h.gch".

Comment: @user3767885, yes, because Sublime doesn't know that you have 2 files. I do not know exactly how to compile multiple files from Sublime, maybe ask someone how knows. But you can always edit in sublime and compile/run from the command line. Or create a Makefile, and configure Sublime to use the Makefile, again I don't know now how to do it.

Comment: I edited your answer to include the full instructions.